# Thai Culture Date labels are Inconsistent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, localization

I faced this Thai [calendar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156408/datepicker-not-showing-correct-year-2021-should-be-2564-for-thai-culture) a few days back but it got resolved with great community help.

Following the above bug, The Thai culture labels or date format are inconsistent when we update the Phone language (English --> Thai). Please check the labels displaying as 2021 instead of 2564.

[image]

Though the DatePicker is displaying fine:

[image]

To display the date label, we are doing:

`dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

We are updating the CultureInfo at App.cs on configuration changed:

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged([NotNull] Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            var javaLocale = newConfig.Locales.Get(0);
            if (javaLocale != null)
            {
                ResetNetLocale(javaLocale);
            }
        }

        private static void ResetNetLocale([NotNull] Locale javaLocale)
        {
            var cultureInfo = javaLocale.TryGetCultureInfo() ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        }
```

At listview item or other views to update the CultureInfo we are also using:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Though other regions/culture labels eg. (France, German, etc.) are displaying fine. The only problem we are facing in Thai culture.

Any hint to solve the issue would be really helpful.

Comment: FYI: There are 3rd party open-source calendars and date pickers widgets that are Thai/Buddhist Calendar compliant as this has been a known issue in ASOP for a while. I have never personally looked at the ASOP issues (open or closed) across the various Android API levels related to this but the fact that 3rd parties have developed and maintained alternatives to using the default Android widgets strictly for `ThaiBuddhistCalendar` means you might need to look at them also...

Answer (score 0):

When i change the device system language from English to Thai, the label would show the 2564 well.

If you still show the 2021, add the code below to set the Thai culture in page.xaml.cs would make it display 2564 at first time.

```
   public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH");

    }
 }
```

Comment: Wendy, The above solution is not working. I created a bug here(https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14963).

Comment: This could change the 2021 to 2564 in the datepicker label. But for the datepicker dialog, the 2021 could not been changed like the previous thread i done before.